# Using sed to extract string values

Tags: regex, string, unix, sed

How would someone use **sed** to go about reordering groups of substrings within a string separated by commas?

For instance,

**hello bob, my name is, joseph**

becomes:

**joseph, My name is, hello bob**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this as the test file:

```
$ cat file
hello bob, my name is, joseph
```

We can reorder the fields as you like with:

```
$ sed -E 's/([^,]*), *([^,]*), *([^,]*)/\3, \2, \1/' file
joseph, my name is, hello bob
```

#### How it works

A `sed` substitute command has the form `s/old/new/`.  This replaces `old` with `new` where `old` is a regex.  In this case, `old` is:

```
([^,]*), *([^,]*), *([^,]*)
```

The items in parens are groups.  This separates the line into three comma-separated groups.  We can refer to these three groups as `\1`, `\2`, and `\3` respectively.  In the `new` text, then, we use:

```
\3, \2, \1
```

This reverses the order of the groups, putting the third first and the first last, as you requested.

#### Handling an indefinite number of columns

If we want to reverse all the substrings but the number of substrings is unknown in advance, then `awk` is a good tool to use:

```
$ awk -F', *' '{for (i=NF;i>0;i--)printf "%s%s",$i,(i>1?", ":"\n")}' file
joseph, my name is, hello bob
```

`-F', *'` indicates that we want to use a comma optionally followed spaces as the field delimiter.

`for (i=NF;i>0;i--)printf "%s%s",$i,(i>1?", ":"\n")` loops in reverse over each field and prints it followed either by `,` or, for the last one, a newline.

#### Reversing words within substrings

Here is an example of reversing words within a substring:

```
$ sed -E 's/([^ ,]*) ([^,]*), /\2 \1, /' file
bob hello, my name is, joseph
```

Here is an example of reversing the words within a substring while also reversing substring order:

```
$ sed -E 's/([^ ,]*) ([^,]*), *([^,]*), *([^,]*)/\4, \3, \2 \1/' file
joseph, my name is, bob hello
```

Comment: What if there is an indefinite amount of groups?

Comment: @KennyLau In that case, I would use `awk`.  See updated answer for the awk code.

Comment: Thanks!  What if I wanted to use sed to then reorder words within the same group as well?

Comment: @user OK.  I added some examples of that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [awk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) :

```
awk -F', ' '{ print $3 ", " $2 ", " $1 }' <<< "hello bob, my name is, joseph"
#joseph, my name is, hello bob
```

---

**Update:**
Based on [@andlrc's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/887539/andlrc) comment, this solution is simpler:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "}{print $3, $2, $1}' <<< "hello bob, my name is, joseph"
```

Comment: You can use `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "}{print $3, $2, $1}'`, this way you don't need to hardcode `, ` 3 times

Comment: Always learning... I'll update my answer with your comment, tks !