# Using sed to reorder string values within groups

Tags: regex, string, unix, sed, regex-group

Similar to [Using sed to extract string values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36949509/using-sed-to-extract-string-values)

but I would like to know how to reorder string values within side of groups.

For example,

**My name, is bob, hello.**

to

**Hello, Bob is, my name**

and also

**Steve Joseph Angelo.,**

to

**Angelo, Steve, Joseph**

I understand it is going to require the regex similar to :
**sed -E 's/([^ ]*), *([^,]*), *([^,]*)/\3, \2, \1/' name.txt**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
sed -E 's/([^,]*),([^ ]*) ([^,]*),([^.]*)\./\4, \2 \3, \1/'
```

Comment: Just updated the post.  So how do we change "is Bob" to "Bob is" ?

Comment: That only makes it become "hello, is bob,My name"     --> it does not change it to "bob is"

Comment: What about if it was sep by spaces?   For instance,   Steve Mike Angelo., to become   Angelo, Mike, Steve    ?

Comment: @user match groups of non-space characters separated by spaces